# How to upload a standalone POM to Azure artifacts?

Tags: azure, maven, jar, pom.xml, azure-artifacts

Previously I have successfully uploaded the POM file to Azure Artifacts using

```
mvn  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file     
-Dpackaging=jar    
-DrepositoryId=repoID    
-Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/path    
-DgroupId=groupId    
-DartifactId=artifactId    
-Dversion=version     
-Dfile=artifactId-version.jar
-DpomFile=artifactId-version.pom
```

This works very well, but the problem is I have to now upload an artifact with only POM and without JAR
https://repository.jboss.org/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs-all/3.0.19.Final/

I tried this but it is failing

```
mvn  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file    
-Dpackaging=jar       
-DrepositoryId=repoID       
-Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/path    
-DgroupId=org.jboss.resteasy     
-DartifactId=resteasy-jaxrs-all        
-Dversion=3.0.19.Final     
-DpomFile=resteasy-jaxrs-all-3.0.19.Final.pom
```

I am getting the following error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- deploy:2.4:deploy-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.793 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-25T16:05:39+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The parameters 'file' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

Comment: When deploying a POM without a JAR file, you don't need the -Dfile parameter.

Comment: The maven-deploy-plugin is expecting a JAR file, but since you only want to deploy the POM, you should omit the -Dfile parameter.

Comment: Try this :

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file \
  -Dpackaging=pom \
  -DrepositoryId=repoID \
  -Durl=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/path \
  -DgroupId=org.jboss.resteasy \
  -DartifactId=resteasy-jaxrs-all \
  -Dversion=3.0.19.Final \
  -DpomFile=resteasy-jaxrs-all-3.0.19.Final.pom`

Comment: @DasariKamali Yeah I tried it, if you see the command I have executed you will see I have not added -Dfile parameter. But still it is giving the error

Answer (score 0):

`file` is a required parameter in Apache Maven Deploy Plugin. See the detailed info from [deploy:deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). To publish an artifact with only pom and without jar, you can change the value of `packaging` to `pom` and set `file` to your pom file. For example,

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging=pom -DrepositoryId=YourRepoID -DgroupId=YourGroupID -DartifactId=YourArtifactID -Dversion=7.0-SNAPSHOT -DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=pom.xml
```

Checking the package in Azure artifact, only pom is published.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I see in your parameters you have given it as pom.xml but the file name and extension is fileName.pom is this ok?

Comment: I ran mvn  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file  -Dpackaging=pom   -DrepositoryId=repoId   -Durl="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/path"  -DgroupId=org.jboss.resteasy  -DartifactId=resteasy-jaxrs-all  -Dversion=3.0.19.Final  -Dfile=resteasy-jaxrs-all-3.0.19.Final.pom   -DpomFile=resteasy-jaxrs-all-3.0.19.Final.pom

Comment: I got the following error:

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Specified pomFile does not exist -> [Help 1]

Comment: Full error log

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Specified pomFile does not exist -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Specified pomFile does not exist
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
 
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Specified pomFile does not exist

Comment: @FullStack Geek, I run the command in the root folder of my project. When I have `pom.xml` in the root folder of my project.  Using `-DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=pom.xml` works without any issue.  If I have `my-app-7.0-20240126.062629-1.pom` in the root folder of my project. using `-DpomFile=my-app-7.0-20240126.062629-1.pom -Dfile=my-app-7.0-20240126.062629-1.pom` works. Ensure the pom file you used is in the working directory when you run the command.

Comment: using -DpomFile=my-app-7.0-20240126.062629-1.pom -Dfile=my-app-7.0-20240126.062629-1.pom works

It is not working, can you try it once and see, I'm running the cmd in same folder but it is saying  Specified pomFile does not exist

Comment: Tested again on my side, it still works. I try to upload a screenshot to my answer above, but it keeps failing... Please check whether your pom file is in your working directory. `my-app-7.0-20240126.062629-1.pom` is in my working directory.